# Synchronizing two different signals with different timeframes

Tags: python, signal-processing, sensors

I have two different signals coming from heterogeneous sensors (namely odometry and range sensors).
The odometry is sampled with a variable frequency and each sample is provided with its own timestamp and value (let's call it `odometry_data`). The other signal is sampled from a range sensor providing samples at a variable frequency and basically different from the odometry one, we call it `ranges_data`. The average sampling frequency of `odometry_data` is higher than the average sampling frequency of `ranges_data`.

Now, I want to synchronize/align the samples of `ranges_data` to those of `odometry_data` in such a way that for each timestamp of `odometry_data` I have a corresponding sample of `ranges_data`. In order to do that, I was thinking about using some interpolation to reconstruct the `ranges_data` that are not available for the corresponding `odometry_data` and I was wondering if is there a way, in Python, to smartly solve this problem.

Both `odometry_data` and `ranges_data` are stored as Pandas DataFrames.
In order to better understand the problem, I describe below some rows of the data.

| timestamp | odometry |
| --- | --- |
| 1,649,856,265.5996303558 | 0.000000 |
| 1,649,856,265.6247301102 | 0.000000 |
| 1,649,856,265.6498117447 | 0.000000 |
| 1,649,856,265.6750459671 | 0.001005 |
| 1,649,856,265.7001047134 | 0.000503 |
| 1,649,856,265.7252266407 | 0.000503 |
| 1,649,856,265.7502796650 | 0.001005 |
| 1,649,856,265.7754957676 | 0.001508 |
| 1,649,856,265.8005714417 | 0.000503 |
| 1,649,856,265.8256890774 | 0.000000 |

and for the range sensor:

| timestamp | ranges |
| --- | --- |
| 1,649,856,265.6269996166 | 171.0 |
| 1,649,856,265.6690001488 | 160.0 |
| 1,649,856,265.7299997807 | 168.0 |
| 1,649,856,265.7790000439 | 174.0 |
| 1,649,856,265.8319997787 | 160.0 |
| 1,649,856,265.9149999619 | 165.0 |
| 1,649,856,265.9489994049 | 165.0 |
| 1,649,856,266.0070002079 | 160.0 |
| 1,649,856,266.0629999638 | 168.0 |
| 1,649,856,266.0969996452 | 165.0 |

My desiderata would be something like the following:

| timestamp | odometry | ranges |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1,649,856,265.5996303558 | 0.000000 | 168.0 |
| 1,649,856,265.6247301102 | 0.000000 | 171.0 |
| 1,649,856,265.6498117447 | 0.000000 | 165.0 |
| 1,649,856,265.6750459671 | 0.001005 | 160.0 |
| 1,649,856,265.7001047134 | 0.000503 | 164.0 |
| 1,649,856,265.7252266407 | 0.000503 | 168.0 |
| 1,649,856,265.7502796650 | 0.001005 | 172.0 |
| 1,649,856,265.7754957676 | 0.001508 | 174.0 |
| 1,649,856,265.8005714417 | 0.000503 | 165.0 |
| 1,649,856,265.8256890774 | 0.000000 | 160.0 |

Your help on that would be really appreciated!

Comment: Could you use the slower frequency as clock and get a higher frequency value each time a lower frequency signal is stored? This way you would be limited to a sensor resolution of the slowest frequency, but it sounds like you want that.

Comment: @Ovski that is not exactly what I want. I cannot downsample to the slower frequency as I would lose the odometry samples and that is not acceptable for my application.

Comment: Calculate some interpolation function and compute its values at desired points in time. Take a look at [scipy.interpolate.interp1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html). Treat time as x, ranges as y.